# Python Telegrambot in Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio, python-multithreading, python-telegram-bot

I have a relatively complex program which processes data from different interfaces. For this purpose, each interface runs in its own thread. The threads exchange data via queues.
When certain events occur, I am notified via Telegram.
I now need to update the Python version (v3.8 -> v3.11) and therefore also the Telegram library (v8 ->v20.5).

I am now having problems with the new implementation with async functions.

```
import threading
import logging
import asyncio
import time
from telegram import ForceReply, Update
from telegram.ext import Application, CommandHandler, ContextTypes, MessageHandler, filters

class TelegramBotHandler():
    def __init__(self):
        self.application = Application.builder().token(TOKEN).build()
        self.application.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", self.help_command))


    def runPolling(self):
        self.application.run_polling(allowed_updates=Update.ALL_TYPES)

    async def help_command(self, update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
        await update.message.reply_text("Help!")

    def queuehandler(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(60)
            # Here I regularly process other thread data from the queue 
            self.application.bot.send_message(MSG_ID, "Hello World")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    telebot = TelegramBotHandler()
    telebotthread = threading.Thread(target=telebot.runPolling, args=())
    telebotthread.start()
    queuehandlerthread = threading.Thread(target=telebot.queuehandler, args=())
    queuehandlerthread.start()
```

I have tried various options unfortunately without success. I would like to understand how I can run Async Functions (which seem to be required by the Telegram library now) in a thread.

Answer (score 0):

To run an async function outside of async function you can use `asyncio.run(function())`

To run it within an async function you can just use await keyword before the function call just as you did here `await update.message.reply_text("Help!")`